# Which ship sank and made the news for its chaotic evacuation around the year 1912?

Tags: europe, ships, 1910s

A [Romanian newspaper](http://www.digibuc.ro/proxy/?px=aHR0cDovL2RpZ2l0b29sLmRjLmJtbXMucm86ODg4MS9SL01HWUJZNzdWRk1IMTNYUEE2UUYzTDk2TUlJRzdGNTlHVjRYQVNJNDlYWTc1RUFURjdNLTA2MDQ2P2Z1bmM9cmVzdWx0cy1qdW1wLWZ1bGwmYW1wO3NldF9lbnRyeT0wMDAwMTMmYW1wO3NldF9udW1iZXI9MDI5NjY3JmFtcDtiYXNlPUdFTjAx) from April 1912 covers the Titanic's sinking, and mentions, in contrast to the orderly evacuation of the ship, the not so orderly evacuation of another (Note that the date is the 6th of April 1912, due to Romania using a different calendar back then. By the new calendar rules it should be the 19th of April 1912. The article in question is the one below "***1400 de morti!***" i.e. "1400 dead!", on the front page).

It says the ship sank "a few years ago". It highlights the chaotic behavior of the passengers, explicitly mentioning them using knives to make their way (through other passengers) to the lifeboats.

Which ship could the article be referring to?

Comment: Do you have a link to the newspaper, or the title and date it was published?

Comment: @sempaiscuba yes, here's the newspaper: https://bit.ly/2Ho0ptS Note that the date is the 6th of April 1912, due to Romania using a different calendar back then. By the new calendar rules it should be 19th of April 1912. The article in question is the one below "1400 de morti!" i.e. "1400 dead!", on the front page.

Comment: In case it helps you narrow this down to find the answer, wikipedia has a (possibly incomplete) [list of shipwrecks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_shipwrecks_in_1912) from that year.

Comment: post a good link please

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best candidate appears to be the SS Sirio, from 1906. It's "a few years ago" relative to the article and it fits the rest of the description well:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS_Sirio

> The shipwreck gained notoriety because the captain, Giuseppe Piccone, abandoned ship at the first opportunity.
>
> A panic broke out on the ship, with people being trampled and others throwing themselves in the sea while knife-fights broke out over the lifeboats. Terrifying scenes of mothers grieving over their drowned children were described. One report claimed that the captain and his officers tried to restore order, but it soon emerged that he had been the first to abandon ship.